# After installing apk in android phone and run app, its now appearing anything just white screen like in the picture, why is happening this?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

This is the image of the app appearing after installing the android apk

[App white screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT8BS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It might be a Corrupted apk file you install. install it again. if issue does not resolved then install the apk package from another source

Answer (score 0):

**If this is a random apk you found online**

```
        Perhaps it's meant to be a white page and have that scammy look
```

**If this is your application**

It is caused because of android's cold start while the app loads to memory, and it can be avoided with this:

```
            java
javapublic class OnboardingWithCenterAnimationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            public static final int STARTUP_DELAY = 300;
            public static final int ANIM_ITEM_DURATION = 1000;
            public static final int ITEM_DELAY = 300;
            
            private boolean animationStarted = false;
            
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_onboarding_center);
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
            
                if (!hasFocus || animationStarted) {
                    return;
                }
            
                animate();
            
                super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
            }
            
            private void animate() {
                ImageView logoImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_logo);
                ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
            
                ViewCompat.animate(logoImageView)
                    .translationY(-250)
                    .setStartDelay(STARTUP_DELAY)
                    .setDuration(ANIM_ITEM_DURATION).setInterpolator(
                        new DecelerateInterpolator(1.2f)).start();
            
                for (int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View v = container.getChildAt(i);
                    ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat viewAnimator;
            
                    if (!(v instanceof Button)) {
                        viewAnimator = ViewCompat.animate(v)
                                .translationY(50).alpha(1)
                                .setStartDelay((ITEM_DELAY * i) + 500)
                                .setDuration(1000);
                    } else {
                        viewAnimator = ViewCompat.animate(v)
                                .scaleY(1).scaleX(1)
                                .setStartDelay((ITEM_DELAY * i) + 500)
                                .setDuration(500);
                    }
            
                    viewAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).start();
                }
            }
            }
        
        
        Layout
        
                java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="144dp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
                >
            
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:alpha="0"
                    android:text="Hello world"         android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    tools:alpha="1"
                    />
            
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:alpha="0"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="This a nice text"
                  android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    tools:alpha="1"
                    />
            
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_choice1"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                    android:scaleX="0"
                    android:scaleY="0"
                    android:text="A nice choice"
                    android:theme="@style/Button"
                    />
            
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_choice2"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:scaleX="0"
                    android:scaleY="0"
                    android:text="Far better!"
                    android:theme="@style/Button"
                    />
            
            </LinearLayout>
            
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/img_face"
                tools:visibility="gone"
                />
            </FrameLayout>
    
    
    
    img face 
    
        java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:opacity="opaque">
    
    <item android:drawable="?colorPrimary"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/img_face"/>
    </item> 

Details can be found here http://saulmm.github.io/avoding-android-cold-starts
```

Comment: Its my app, where should I put this code, I didn`t build the apk with andorid studio but with the recommended steps in expo?

Comment: @Emily consider reading this guide http://saulmm.github.io/avoding-android-cold-starts excuse my bad response format i am new to stack and im working on it